We have 1,000+ visits per day (September 2013)
In January 2013 we passed 500 visit per day. 
Towards the end of September 2013, we passed 1,000 visits per day.
I just thought it was good to celebrate the growth of the site. Presumably most of this traffic is coming from Google deciding that answers on our site are relevant to what people are searching for. I look forward to when we reach 1,500 visits per day and move another one of our Area 51 statistics into the "green".



Bring out the party hats!
